# Devise email routing to ip instead of domain name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am sending the password reset instructions via the default devise password reset instructions email. When I click on the change password it routes me to the localhost:3000 in my local machine but in production it is routing to some ip. I think it is of the cloud server we are hosting on, how to change this to the domain name ?

This is the devise password reset instructions:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

How to change this do I have to set the url hardcoded to the domains ? Because we have a staging and production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928842/sending-confirmation-emails-with-devise/61929293#61929293) I've just given a quick answer on sending emails in production in general.

In your particular case you are looking for putting the following code in `production.rb`:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'YOUR-APP-NAME.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'https' }`

If you have more than one environment, you configure each environment separately, right? So for staging you would have something like *config/environments/staging.rb* and configure it there.

[More details on action mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views)