# How to send confirmation emails with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  #  :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

How should I configure devise to send confirmation emails when the user signs up?

Comment: in development or production?

Comment: yes a still in development but i will need also in production

Comment: what about in developent

Comment: In development you have all the transactional emails in your console. Try sending a "forgot password" request, and look at your console. You can as well use a gem like https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Comment: thanks i  have got . may be i wish to you continue helping me

Comment: If the answer helped, ticke the "checkmark" so that users know that that is the solution to the question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production, you need to configure a third-party email sending service, like sendgrid. Example:

1. register on heroku.com
2. push the your local app repo to github.com
3. `heroku create`
4. `heroku rename your-app-name`
5. `git push heroku master`
6. `heroku run rake db:migrate`
7. `heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter`

environment.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net', 
  :port => '587', 
  :authentication => :plain, 
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], 
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'], 
  :domain => 'heroku.com', 
  :enable_starttls_auto => true 
}
```

production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your-app-name.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'https' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

That way you will be able to send/receive all devise emails in production

Details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Comment: help me also in development on my local machine

Comment: If the answer helped, ticke the "checkmark" so that users know that that is the solution to the question you asked.

Comment: @mutebigodfrey ^